# Centos 8 split root volume to LVM

Tags: linux, centos, partition, fdisk

I am using CentOs 8 and deployed on cloud infrastructure.

It is attached to root disk at /dev/xvda having size 250GB.

```
Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/xvda1       2048      4095      2048    1M 83 Linux
/dev/xvda2 *     4096 524287966 524283871  250G 83 Linux
```

This root disk contains around 20GB OS related data and other 230 GB is free. I want to re-partition this 230GB space on same disk /dev/xvda to below like.

```
Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
   /dev/xvda1       2048      4095      2048    1M 83 Linux
   /dev/xvda2      4096 524287966         **  100G 83 Linux
   /dev/xvda3      4096 **                **   50G 83 Linux
   /dev/xvda4      4096 **                **   50G 83 Linux
   /dev/xvda5      4096 **                **   20G 83 Linux
   /dev/xvda6      4096 **          524283871  30G 83 Linux
```

Does linux provide any best way to achieve this? I have gone through LVM in linux , mostly it is concerned with partitioning unallocated space(creating LVM on disk destroys any data, in my case its OS itself).

Could someone please guide me ?

Comment: "... mostly it is concerned with partitioning unallocated space." Where does it say this? That is not the point of LVM.

Comment: @Panki It means that creating LVM on disk destroys any data. Hence I would say it concerned with unallocated space

Comment: What are those new partitions going to be used for? 4 relatively small partitions will make it painful to adapt to future storage needs (in other words, are you sure you won't risk needing to resize them?). Depending on your use case, LVM may help and you may just shrink `xvda2`, create `xvda3` and setup LVM on it (only) and create 4 LVs, possibly leaving some free space in the volume group for future allocation.

Comment: CentOS uses the XFS filesystem by default and XFS can't be shrunk, which won't help to solve this specific question.